Suspending coroutine and resuming later in boost.Asio
In my application, I use Asio for asynchronous websockets and coroutines (custom websocket server). It works in a way that I have callback which is called when data is received and by interacting with client-specific object I can send data to them. However, as my application is designed as pure request-response (both client-server and server-client), I came up with the idea of simplifying workflow by making on-data-receive callback "transfer" data to coroutine that caused client to respond with this data. Basic example may look like this:
asio::io_context ctx(1);

asio::awaitable<void> client_do_X(client& cl) {

    // Send X and get response from on_data?
    auto data = co_await cl.send("X");

    // Use data...
}

asio::awaitable<void> client_do_Y(client& cl) {

    // Send Y and get response from on_data?
    auto data = co_await cl.send("Y");

    // Use data...
}

asio::awaitable<void> on_data(client& cl, std::string_view data) {

    if (is_result_of_X(data)) {

        // Transfer data to client_do_X and resume it?
    } else if (is_result_of_Y(data)) {

        // Transfer data to client_do_Y and resume it?
    }
}

asio::awaitable<void> co_main() {

    server s;

    s.on_data(on_data);

    co_await s.start();
}

int main() {

    co_spawn(ctx, co_main, asio::detached);

    ctx.run();
}

However, I'm not sure if I can do this with Asio and what specifically I would want to use. After some research, I came across std::async_initiate and std::async_compose, but they seem to operate on callbacks and don't give me direct control over suspending/resuming which I need to implement that.
How would I implement suspending of coroutine which sends request and resume and transfer data from on_data callback when response is received?
